# Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm with an arbitrary initial state

Tags: c, algorithm, permutation

What must be changed in a standard Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter if values in the initial array are not ordered? For example, my initial array is 312 and I want to generate the following result:

```
312
321
231
213
123
132
```

I could introduce an additional array which defines the initial weight of each number, e.g. w[3]=1, w[1]=2, and w[2]=3 and then compare weights instead of values in the algorithm, but is it possible to do without this - I want to apply the algorithm to a problem where this additional array is not convenient? I am looking for solution in C.

Comment: If you specifically want the order generated by SJT, you'll have to keep track of where each element is and what direction it's moving in, so I don't think you can avoid needing at least O(n) extra space. (There are other algorithms that will give you all permutations, but they won't give the exact same order.)

Comment: I can accept any order where the consecutive permutations differ only by one swap of elements which are next to each other. I have no requirements for the final permutation, i.e. it is not neccessary that the final permutation differ from the first one only in one swap.

Comment: In that case, have a look at Heap's algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm

Comment: Unfortunately, Heap's algorithm is not working by swapping adjacent elements, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, adjacent, no. I overlooked that part, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the Johnson-Trotter algorithm on an array of indices as normal. Instead of displaying the indices, however, display the items at each respective index in a separate array containing arbitrary elements in an arbitrary order.

As a simple example (not in C, but the idea is the same):

```py
from trotter import Permutations

index_permutations = Permutations(3, [0, 1, 2])

items = [3, 1, 2]

print("Indices -> Items")
for indices in index_permutations:
    print("{} -> {}".format(indices, [items[i] for i in indices]))
```

Output:

```
Indices -> Items
[0, 1, 2] -> [3, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 1] -> [3, 2, 1]
[2, 0, 1] -> [2, 3, 1]
[2, 1, 0] -> [2, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 0] -> [1, 2, 3]
[1, 0, 2] -> [1, 3, 2]
```